# Ranking a column sourced from another column

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to display values in a column in ascending order without altering the order of the original column. For this I created a new column and populated it with the values from the original column. Original values change often, so I would like to use a formula and not "paste special". The setup is as follows:

[image]

How could I sensibly ranke the values in "Ranked RoR%" in ascending order? When I use sort they immediately revert to their original values, since they are sourced from the column RoR%. Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=SMALL(A:A,ROW(1:1))
```

This will display the smallest value in column A. If you drag down the formula it'll change ROW(1:1) to ROW(2:2) and so on displaying the N-th smallest value regardless of the order in column A. At the end you should have the values of column A in an ascending order.

Comment: Brilliant! There is a title in the column though, which leads to a DIV error. Is there a more open formula, which allows for the number of column entries to change dynamically, instead of writing =SMALL($A$2:$A$100,ROW(1:1)) ?

Comment: That's odd...SMALL should ignore any text values. I tried myself here before posting.
There's another way of making a dynamic range for your SMALL formula, but it's more complex...
You sure the error is not coming from anywhere else? I mean #DIV/0 errors are not likely to happen with SMALL functions as it points to a division by zero.

If this stills not working for you I can offer another solution. I just want to keep the solution as simple as possible.